# Is the basic Golub and Reinsch algorithm for calculating the SVD guaranteed to converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

It seems like the algorithm for calculating the SVD depends on an implicit implementation of the shifted QR algorithm to diagonalize a bidiagonal matrix, but the QR algorithm isnt guaranteed to always converge except under special conditions (the only one of which I could find is for when the absolute values of the eigenvalues are distinct). Does this mean this algorithm isnt guaranteed to converge as well?

Comment: It may depend on what "converge" means. The matrix sequence may not converge, but the block split can nevertheless be sufficient to get an eigen-decomposition.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if a split is guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, in the shifted QR there should form blocks for close clusters of eigenvalues, and the subdiagonal entries between the blocks should converge to zero, the faster the more distant the clusters. Convergence inside clusters can be slow and imprecise, sensitive to previous rounding and truncation errors, it might need some extra tricks.

Comment: Notice that the SVD computation proceeds via the diagonalization of a symmetric matrix, which reduces to tridiagonal in Hessenberg form. In this case the shifted QR or bulge-chasing methods have even more guarantees for convergence.